# why flink stops my stream application?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My code uses readTextFile to read log files, and when i run the jar in Flink (`/opt/flink-1.0.3/bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 2 /home/flink/flink-json-0.1.jar`), it processes successfully the lines inside and stops my application instead of being waiting for new lines.
Do i need some param for doing it?

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val stream = env.readTextFile("hdfs:///test/ignicion.io")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment.readFileStream(String filePath, long intervalMillis, WatchType watchType)
```

For the WatchType you have the following options

- ONLY_NEW_FILES,
- REPROCESS_WITH_APPENDED,
- PROCESS_ONLY_APPENDED;

The stream from

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment.readTextFile(String filePath, String charsetName)
```

will be finished after reading all files. I think, it is mainly for local testing during development.

Comment: Same result: `env.readFileStream("hdfs:///test/ignicion.io",100,FileMonitoringFunction.WatchType.PROCESS_ONLY_APPENDED)`

Comment: Dou you mean it also stops immediately?